# Overwriting User Id in Branch Metrics with two users on one device

Tags: analytics, branch.io

I'm using Branch Metrics for app attribution and noticed that if you login as two separate people from one device, it replaces the user ID we associate for all previous calls even if it was two separate accounts from one device.

Is this the expected behavior? Seems to throw our tracking off.

Answer (score 2):

This could be due to you forgetting to make a logout call when the user is logged out (and thus before the second of those two people logs in).

In Objective-C, be sure to call

```
[[Branch getInstance] logout];
```

anywhere that you're logging out users. If, for example, you use a service like Facebook, put it alongside the Facebook SDK's logout call in your code.